# How to test Spring Cloud Stream when there are multiple messages?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-test

I want to test Spring Cloud Stream Sink with multiple messages. Let's say I have a processor class like this:

```java
@Component
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class TestProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    public void process(@Payload List<String> values) {
        values.forEach(s -> processor.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(s).build()));
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test it. Here is my test class:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProcessorTest {
    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;
    @Autowired
    private MessageCollector collector;

    @Test
    public void cdrFilterTriggerFlow_whenNoTrigger_shouldNoResponse() throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {
        processor.input().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(List.of("a", "b", "c")).build());
        Object payload = collector.forChannel(processor.output()).poll().getPayload();
        assertNotNull(payload);
    }
}
```

In the payload I'm only getting `"a"`. How can I get all `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` in the payload? Or at least there are three messages in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep calling `poll()` until you get `null`.